# SQL column for counting certain character in EACH CELL in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possbile to (simply) create an SQL column that counts the appearence of a character in EACH CELL in another column?

For example, I have a table with a column storing items, where each item is separated by a comma (,):

```
Index | Items
-------------
1     | Book
2     | Book, Chair
3     | Book, Chair, Box
4     | NULL
```

I want to add a column specifying the number of items in the table, so it looks like this:

```
Index | Items             | Amount
---------------------------------------
1     | Book              | 1
2     | Book, Chair       | 2
3     | Book, Chair, Box  | 3
4     | NULL              | 0
```

Would that be possible?

*(I am using MS SQL Server)*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. If you have the chance, then fix your data model

Comment: Ok, what should be a better separtor (; etc.)? Would the additional column I want to create/add to the table be possible if change the comma to anohter character?

I am able to change all the commas if wanted, but I must create a counter column following the model above!

Comment: No separator at all. Create a proper one-to-many relationship table and store each item in a single row

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

A general mechanism is to count commas:

```
select coalesce( 1 + length(items) - length(replace(items, ',', '')), 0)
```

EDIT:

in SQL Server, you can do:

```
select coalesce( 1 + len(items) - len(replace(items, ',', '')), 0) 
from all_items;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me. Suppose that my table is named "All_Items" and that the column storing items is called "Items". How shall I apply your idea to create the column I want?